# Proportionally move stack of objects

Tags: transforms

I'm using Blender 2.8 and I have a stack of sicks that I'm trying to compress evenly. I thought I'd be able to use the proportional edit feature to do this but I feel like I'm doing something wrong:

[image]

When I try to move these proportionally they all move together up the Z axis. Am I missing something?

It does work for scaling, but that's not what I'm after. I can position this manually, but I would love to be able to spread these quickly.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the Header > Pivot Point dropdown, there's an 'Origins Only' option. If you check that, and choose the appropriate pivot about which to scale  (try 'Median'), you will be able to spread/bring together your objects without affecting their geometry.

That looks from your picture to be <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, with no proportional editing.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that to work immediately, but perhaps the pivot is off. I'll mess around a bit in the morning and see if I can get this to work, it definitely sounds like the right approach.

Comment: @Daniel ..see edit..